# multiple jQuery Scripts with Telerik ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik

I'm having a problem using two jQuery scripts at one page. 
One is of my bootstrap template and the second one is my Telerik JQuery (UI components).

I have been searching all over the internet for a sollution and I found the "jQuery.noConflict()" method.

The suggestion was to place this method before the script I want to use..(?) But the Telerik components are created using Html Helpers :

example:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<Schoolproject.Models.ViewModels.ShiftViewModel>()
    .Name("scheduler")
    .Date(DateTime.Today)
    .StartTime(new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 11, 00, 00))
    .WorkDayStart(new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 00, 00, 00))
    .WorkDayEnd(new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 23, 59, 59))
    .WorkWeekStart(0)
    .WorkWeekEnd(6)
    .Height(600)

    .Views(views =>
    {
        views.DayView(dayView => dayView.WorkDayCommand(false));
        views.WeekView(weekView => weekView.Selected(true));
        views.WeekView(weekView => weekView.WorkDayCommand(false));
        views.MonthView();
        views.AgendaView();
    })

    .Resources(resource =>
    {
        resource.Add(m => m.UserId)
            .Title("Personeel")
            .DataTextField("Text")
            .DataValueField("Value")
            .DataColorField("Color")
            .BindTo(new[] {
                    new { Text = "Alex", Value = 1, Color = "#f8a398" } ,
                    new { Text = "Bob", Value = 2, Color = "#51a0ed" } ,
                    new { Text = "Charlie", Value = 3, Color = "#56ca85" }

            });


    })

    .DataSource(d => d
    .Model(m =>
    {
        m.Id(f => f.ShiftId);
        m.Field(f => f.UserId).DefaultValue(1);
        m.Field(f => f.IsPublished == true);

    })
    .Events(e => e.Error("error_handler"))
    .Read("Availabilities_Read", "Scheduler")
    .Create("Availabilities_Create", "Scheduler")
    .Update("Availabilities_Update", "Scheduler")
    .Destroy("Availabilities_Destroy", "Scheduler")
    )
    )
```

My 2 jQuery files are rendered in my "Shared/_LayoutPage.cshtml"

Could someone please tell me where i should add this jQuery.noConflift() method to make my Telerik UI components work?

Thanks in advance,

N00By programmer

Comment: the `jquery UI` is dependent on the `jquery` you have to load first `jquery` then `jqueryUI`. all the jquery scripts should load at very first time

Comment: @JohnAnkanna , I tried your sollution and it worked !!  My mistake was that i've put my Telerik Jquery UI in the HEAD section en the jquery File of my template at the end of the body section. 
I switched the two and now it works...

No extra code needed. :))))

Comment: @Polarbear90 if that useful just make the comment useful with highlighting so some one could notice that

Comment: @JohnAnkanna , haha this will sound awkward , but I don't see how to highlight your comment xD.
Thats why i added a new answer with a pointer to you ;)

Comment: @Polarbear90 when you hover on the left side you can see the the button for pointing upwards

Comment: @JohnAnkanna, there are no upvote buttons when i hover over the comments (0_o)

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=a52580a

Answer (score 1):

You can define $.noConflict() where you added your javascript references i.e. Layout page in MVC as shown below:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="other_lib.js"></script>

<script>
    $.noConflict();
    jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
      // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
    });
    // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

On the other hand please be sure that you have loaded the javascript files in right order. Here is an example order in Layout page:

```
<head>        
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2015.1.408/jquery.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2015.1.408/jszip.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2015.1.408/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2015.1.408/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.modernizr.custom.js")"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Why is other_lib.js before jquery.js?

Comment: The first loaded js is **jquery.min.js** and the second one is **jszip.min.js**. What are the other libs???

Comment: Murat, I do not know, this is why I am asking, since this part is unclear for me from your first example. Otherwise I understand the answer and agree, but this small nuance bothers me and prevents me from upvoting :)

Comment: The important point is that: If **js2** use some methods in **js1**, then you have to load **js1** first and then **js2**. So, it makes so much difference when there are dependency between javascript files. Generally, it is better to load jquery or commonly used javascript files first.

Comment: Murat, I will try to ask my question again. Why is other_lib.js before jquery.js in your example when jquery.js clearly does not depent on other_lib.js? I quote your example:
<script src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

Comment: I am so sorry, I just focused on my example (second part) and really surprised why you asked this. Actually it is an example from https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/ page and you are right. As I said in the previous comment, other_lib.js must be loaded later than jquery.js. I updated my answer, but it is not my fault :(

Comment: Murat, that was the last obstacle in my opvite's way :)

Comment: I agree with you and edited my answer so that the others can also get benefit from this answer. Many thanks for helping me to be aware of the mistake ;)

Comment: @MuratYıldız , thank you for your effort helping me. The problem is solved by adding the template jQuery file to the head section of my Layout page, and my Telerik kendo jQuery file to the end of my body section.

I didn't even have to use the jQuery.noConflict method in my Layout page..
I checked and it's defined in the jQuery file of the template.. If you want I can send you the code. 

So thanks again for checking. 

Thanks to all btw. :)

Answer (score 0):

For those who were wondering what the sollution is:

I've put the jQuery file of the Template in the < head > section, and the jQuery file of Kendo at the end of the < body > section.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>ScheduleMe | @ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/font-awesome/css")

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")


</head>
<body>

    <!-- Wrapper-->
    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        @Html.Partial("_Navigation")

        <!-- Page wraper -->
        <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg">

            <!-- Top Navbar -->
            @Html.Partial("_TopNavbar")

            <!-- Main view  -->
            @RenderBody()

            <!-- Footer -->
            @Html.Partial("_Footer")

        </div>
        <!-- End page wrapper-->

    </div>
    <!-- End wrapper-->

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/metsiMenu")
    @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/pace")
    @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/slimScroll")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/inspinia")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo/css")

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

My  Kendo object is generated without any problems + the template functionalities are also working!

Me = Happy !

Thank you John Ankanna for providing this answer , and the others for the effort and time !